# Using slice pipe on data for child component property causes infinite calls to @Input set method

Tags: angular, typescript, input, slice

When adding a slice pipe to the data object below, and with that data being sent to the child component's `@Input` set method, there are infinite calls to that method. When removing the just the slice pipe from the data object it works as normal, the `@Input` method is only called once.

Parent component template:

```
<ng-container
  *ngIf="[
      { name: 'a', order: 1 },
      { name: 'b', order: 2 },
      { name: 'c', order: 3 },
      { name: 'd', order: 4 },
      { name: 'e', order: 5 }] | slice:0:3 as data"
>
  <slice-pipe-test [testData]="data"></slice-pipe-test>
</ng-container>
```

Child component typescript:

```
  @Input()
  set testData(testData) {
    console.log(testData);
  }
```

Console log showing infinite calls:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B6S9.png)

Full sample code (must add the " | slice:0:3 " to the data object in app.component.html as shown above, which causes the infinite calls, and the browser hangs) :

https://codesandbox.io/s/3dg47

Is this somehow due to change detection / SlicePipe not being pure, and is working as expected? If moving the data object with the slice into the typescript code, and then referencing it in the html template, this problem no longer occurs. How can the slice be kept in the html template without the infinite calls to the child component `@Input` method?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should use the pipe where view is rendered.

In your case,

**slice-pipe-test.component.html**

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of myData | slice:0:3">
      <td>{{item.order}}</td>
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
this.data = [
  { name: 'a', order: 1 },
  { name: 'b', order: 2 },
  { name: 'c', order: 3 },
  { name: 'd', order: 4 },
  { name: 'e', order: 5 }
]
```

**app.component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="data">
      <slice-pipe-test [testData]="data"></slice-pipe-test>
</ng-container>
```

Or slice it from Typescript.

```
this.data = [
  { name: 'a', order: 1 },
  { name: 'b', order: 2 },
  { name: 'c', order: 3 },
  { name: 'd', order: 4 },
  { name: 'e', order: 5 }
].slice(0, 3);
```

Template:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="data">
      <slice-pipe-test [testData]="data"></slice-pipe-test>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: This is a good workaround.  Though due to other reasons, we don't have the ability to put the slice on the table *ngFor. The workaround that we chose is to move the object and slice code into the .ts file. 

However, workarounds aside, I am still curious what the core issue is here, and if it could be a bug with Angular framework.

Also would like to note that " | slice:0:3 " and " .slice(0,3) " both cause infinite calls to the child component @Input set method. (Did you happen to try .slice() on my mockup in codesandbox?)